# How to send an event to UIViewController from another one

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

My application is structured like below:

```
1. UITabbarController
       1.1 UIViewController
       1.2 UINavigationController        
             1.2.1 UIViewController
             1.2.2 UIViewController
             1.2.3 UIViewController
```

They are shown in below order:

```
1, present -> 1.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3
```

After the user finished its job with 1.2.3, 1.2 NavigationController is dismissed.

I want 1.1 UIViewController to know that 1.2.3 has finished its job

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the easy way to perform (but not the performance way) that you can use `NSNotificationcenter`.
1.1 UIViewController wait a notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
        selector:@selector(receiveTestNotification:) 
        name:@"TestNotification"
        object:nil];
```

When 1.2.3 finished its job, post a notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
        postNotificationName:@"TestNotification" 
        object:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use notification to achieve this.

**Notification**

For notification check @Dummy's answer. The benefit of using notification is, it reduce unnecessary coupling between objects.

*Another dirty trick*

As VC 1.1 is part of `UITabbarController`, you can access it using

```
NSArray *viewControllers = [tabBarController viewControllers];
```

Now you can access the VC 1.1 from `viewControllers` array (may be you have to add `iskindofclass` validation), and send messages to it. 
Again, it is a dirty trick. And it is just for information :)